# Changes to code files in wordpress don't appear on the site

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm working on a new design for my website with a wordpress theme called Bello by Wegraphics.

The social media links don't open in a new tab, so I went into **index.php** and added `target="_blank"` to the links for the links, but even after an out-of-cache refresh on the page, the links still open in the current tab...

Social media links are managed within the theme options in that they are added/not added to the markup depending on whether or not a user/page name is specified for the social media platform.

Earlier I had a similar problem with the site footer where I actually had to manually specify the footer text in the theme options because my changes to the code file weren't being applied so I'm sure the theme options have something to do with it, but its beyond me how to get around it...

The URL in question here is [blog.loganyoung.za.net](http://blog.loganyoung.za.net)

What I'd like to know is how I can get my changes to the code files to actually apply on the site when the features are handled by the theme.

If anyone can help me at all, I'd greatly appreciate it.

Comment: do you have a cache in your worpdress ? check for a directory named "cache".

Comment: there is a cache directory there, yes, but its empty according to filezilla

Comment: well... this is probably where the solution is : try to find how to deactivate the cache, or remove the cached file to force the refresh.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was not in the **index.php** file as I had expected.

I had to change the links in the php code in both the page template(page.php) and the single post(single.php) files.

I simply added in the target attribute without modifying the php code.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your site you only need facebook and twitter? So, in the index.php file replace the code between lines 11 and 15

```
        <?php if (get_option('wgcp_facebook_username') !== '') { ?><li><a href="http://www.facebook.com/<?php echo get_option('wgcp_facebook_username'); ?>" class="round-icon sm-facebook">Facebook</a></li><?php } ?>
        <?php if (get_option('wgcp_twitter_username') !== '') { ?><li><a href="http://twitter.com/<?php echo get_option('wgcp_twitter_username'); ?>" class="round-icon sm-twitter">Twitter</a></li><?php } ?>
        <?php if (get_option('wgcp_flickr_username') !== '') { ?><li><a href="http://www.flickr.com/<?php echo get_option('wgcp_flickr_username'); ?>" class="round-icon sm-flickr">Flickr</a></li><?php } ?>
        <?php if (get_option('wgcp_linkedin_username') !== '') { ?><li><a href="http://www.linkedin.com/in/<?php echo get_option('wgcp_linkedin_username'); ?>" class="round-icon sm-linkedin">LinkedIn</a></li><?php } ?>
    </ul>
```

with

```
        <li><a href="http://your facebooklink" class="round-icon sm-facebook" target="_blank">Facebook</a></li>
        <li><a href="http://your twitter link" class="round-icon sm-twitter" target="_blank">Twitter</a></li>
    </ul>
```

That will sidestep the themes social media settings and hard code your links into the page.